# C# has unbalanced the stack (using .tlb)

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have written a COM ATL DLL in C++, Visual Studio 2012.
All worked fine so far.

In this DLL I need to call a function from the .tlb.

This function is defined in the .tlh file as follows:

```
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetRawDataCB (
    /*[in]*/ long address,
    /*[in]*/ long userData,
    /*[out,retval]*/ enum ApiError * pRetVal ) = 0;
```

In my DLL, I call it like this:

```
_pIEtApi->SetRawDataCB((long)(__int64)(&myRawDataCB),(long)this,&result);
if( result != ApiError_NoError)
    return -3;
```

Now when I test my COM DLL from within C#, C# crashes and tells me:

A call to the PInvoke function "ETApi!Alea.Api.RawDataDelegate::Invoke caused an imbalance of the stack.
Most probally the managed PInvoke signature does not match the un-managed target signature.
You should check if the calling convention and the parameters of the PInvoke signature match the un-managed target signature.

Did I do anything wrong when I used the function?

Thank you!

Comment: what is the code in C# which calls this function? Is the calling convention of PInvoke is also stdcall?

Comment: void myobj_RawDataDetected()
        {
            iCounter++;
            this.Text = iCounter + " events";
        }